# Store a stack object in a priority queue

Tags: c++, stl

I have an object

```
priority_queue<SState,vector<SState>,greater<SState> > m_queue;
```

that is a member of class in which SState is an inner strtuct which defined

```
struct SState
{
    SState(int p, int b):priority(p),bbb(b){}
    ~SState(){}
    int priority;
    int bbb;
};
```

and a comparator

```
inline bool operator > (const MyClass::SState& left, const MyClass::SState& right)
{
   return left.priority > right.priority;
}
```

I have a method that create an SState object.

```
m_queue.push(SState(p,b));
```

and in **other** method

```
if (!m_queue.empty())
{

      const SState& state = m_queue.top();
      ...
      m_queue.pop();

}
```

I got an heap corruption.
How to do it right?

Comment: Are you doing anything with the `state` reference after calling `pop`? If so, you're using a dangling reference, which could certainly cause heap corruption. If not, then the problem is not in the code you've posted.

Comment: use bbb as an index to an array

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is presumably that you're using `state` after you call `m_queue.pop();`, resulting in access of a reference to an item that no longer exists. You'll either need to move the `pop` call later into the function, or make a copy of the item after you get a reference to it from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
const SState& state = m_queue.top();
```

There you got reference to heap copy of stack object. But this reference don't extends lifetime of object.

So there

```
  m_queue.pop();
```

object is destructing and you can't use reference to it anymore.